# View rotates first time, but not second time

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

I have the following short code that animates a TextView when I click on a button. When I click the button the first time, it works like expected. But when I click it after that, it does not animate anymore. 
The onClick-Method is called, I checked that. But the animation does not get restarted.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTv);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PropertyValuesHolder rotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("rotationY", 360);
        ObjectAnimator cardAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myTv, rotation);
        cardAnimator.setDuration(500);
        cardAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you tell *"animate this view's rotationY to 360"* degrees - it animates.

Second time you tell *"animate this view's rotationY to 360"* degrees - it still animates, but this time it has nothing to do, because that view is already at 360 degrees.

Explicitly tell, that you want it to be animated from 0 to 360:

```
 PropertyValuesHolder rotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("rotationY", 0, 360);
```